# Single Sign On with Spring Security LDAP Plugin

Tags: spring, grails, ldap, single-sign-on, windows-authentication

Ok so I have an app already wired to my ldap server. User just has to put their username and password in. We have some other grails apps as well that people have to type in their AD credentials. I would like to implement single sign on.

I have version 3.0.2 of the spring security ldap plugin and I am on Grails 3.3.9. From what I've read so far this plugin is required to use single sign on if I am using Spring Security with grails. I have  some code already set up as an attempt but I am still getting the login page instead of being authenticated automatically. The domain is on Windows Server 2012. This app (and the rest of them once I have the config right) will get deployed on a linux server. Here's what I have so far (with some values omitted for security reasons):

`resources.groovy`

```
import tstsupport.UserPasswordEncoderListener
import tstsupport.MyUserDetailsContextMapper
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    userPasswordEncoderListener(UserPasswordEncoderListener)
    ldapUserDetailsMapper(MyUserDetailsContextMapper){

    }
    ldapAuthProvider1(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider,
            "domain.com",
            "ldap://domain.com:389"
    )
}
```

`application.groovy`

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = 'CN=Service Account,CN=Managed Service Accounts,DC=domain,DC=com'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = 'password'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = 'ldap://domain.com:389'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchBase = '...'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = '...'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter= '(sAMAccountName={0})'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveDatabaseRoles = true

grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ['ldapAuthProvider1']
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve SSO with LDAP alone? I think you need to use Kerberos or OAuth 2 via AD FS.

Comment: From what I saw as it pertains to grails, what you said was not mentioned. However I'm a noob in this area so if you found otherwise I'm all ears.

Comment: Me either, hence the comment and not an answer :) I use the Grails 2 series LDAP plugin to, but is just works as you described your current situation. I once tried the grails spring security kerberos plugin and it worked well, but it was complicated to setup/debug and it doesn't work outside the network, so we dismissed it completely. Today, I would use the grails spring security OAuth plugin. We use a non grails webapp connected to MS AD FS and it works well.

Comment: @andi Does OAuth 2 even support SSO with AD creds? It looks like it was meant for social media logins. I saw the docs for the spring security kerberos plugin and it was specifically meant to authenticate domain users without having to type in creds.

Comment: OAuth 2 is just the Standard, even though it's usually used to Auth against social media portals, it works for this scenario. The difficulty, for both kerberos and OAuth, is IMO to get the Admins to help you, or to setup the server by yourself. If you choose to try OAuth, the keyword to search for would be something like "Server 2012 adfs oauth". But keep in mind, I was never involved in a complete setup, so I could be wrong.

Comment: This is a web app which uses LDAP on the server side for authentication. How should SSO be achieved? It's impossible. LDAP would need to use Kerberos based auth do perform SASL ... https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4422 and use 'GSSAPI'. This requires a TGT of the user on the server side. How will it get there?

If you want web-based SSO then you need to use a technology that provides it --> standards based ones are SAML or OIDC. OAuth2 is actually about delegated  authorization.